# Placing two sanitees onto the same stack vent

Tags: plumbing

Is there building code for how far apart, on the same stack vent, sanitees can be from each other?

Is there a stacking order, as in which should be above the other, the sink's vent or the washer's vent?

I've included a sketch for reference (sketch not to size or code)

[image]

Comment: your terminology is messed up, you can't connect fixtures to a stack vent, only to a drain stack.

Comment: Sure you can, @Jasen, it becomes a "wet vent". There are code restrictions in place on where those can be used and how, but it's certainly allowable under the correct situations.

Comment: And the thing you've labeled as washer's vent is washer standpipe.

Comment: Your code may or may not be IPC, or modified/amended IPC. It could be UPC, it could be some made up from whole cloth thing your LAHJ has adopted insead. References to IPC because it's easily available online, and what my code is based on. There are small differences if UPC is your base code.

Comment: @Jasen -thank you for the clarification, much appreciated.

Comment: @Ecnerwal -Thank you as well for the naming correction; washer standpipe vs. washer's vent, much appreciated.  This is how ignorance becomes educated, by those who know teaching those who don't.

Comment: @Ecnerwal -Honestly, and I think it goes without saying, I don't know IPC from UPC or from which LAHJ I may have spun this from.  I'm known for pulling things out of nothing and we all know what zero from zero gets you, which is why I'm on the boards asking questions.

Comment: One thought is that I have seen (in back-to-back men's and women's office restrooms) a flush on one side push water around on the other side.  Check whether any high flow situation like that might be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

How close can they be located on the same drain line?

You can't use one of these, as they are prohibited for connection to "fixtures or appliances with pumping action discharge" ([IPC706.3](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2018P5/chapter-7-sanitary-drainage#IPC2018P5_Ch07_Sec706))

[image: Double-santee]

*[Image source](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.homedepot-static.com%2FproductImages%2Fd2a3e38c-9de9-4102-95ec-cb35d3de97a7%2Fsvn%2Ftees-wyes-c5835hd2-64_1000.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=343167e76a56c8bc1ca53612f969f42dcd8ed1b18403f440e3fd78bbcf8ed56a&ipo=images), no endorsement implied*

If you stack them, you have to follow the [wet-venting](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2018P5/chapter-9-vents#IPC2018P5_Ch09_Sec912) rules for the section of pipe in-between them, or provide a dry vent from the trap arm to the dry section of vent stack. That will normally mean the lower flow vanity goes above the higher flow washer drain, where flow is Drain Fixture Units (DFUs) as used in code for these purposes.

There isn't any prescribed distance between them. They can be butted hub-to-hub or be on different floors of the house, so long as the sizes are correct for the DFU drain size and wet vent rules, or a dry vent of suitable size is provided to solve too much drainage for wet venting to apply.

There *are* generally required clean-outs your drawings don't show.

Comment: -Again, thank you for the information.  I believe I've heard them called double Y-Tee's, and I was told that I could not use them in the application I want, so thank you for the confirmation.  I was further educated by a local plumber at Longley Supply Company regarding lower flow vs higher flow, so placing the sink's vent connection over the washer's standpipe was okay.  Honestly, if I don't have to mess with another pipe, within the remaining time the good lord has given me, I'd be fine, just fine.  If not for my daughter, I'd be working on my art.